# GPL Ghostscript (+ doxygen) on MSYS2 outputs unrecoverable error

Tags: windows-10, doxygen, ghostscript, msys2

I've just installed the MSYS2 subsystem on Windows 10 successfully and also `doxygen` (version `1.9.2`) and `ghostscript` (version `9.53.3 (2020-10-01)`). I want to generate the html doxygen of [this C++ project](https://github.com/LAL-project/linear-arrangement-library.git).

In order to install the latter two I installed the packages:

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-texlive-font-utils
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-texlive-bibtex-extra
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-doxygen
```

At this point, `ghostscript` has already been installed as a dependency of the packages above. When I run `doxygen`, however, I get the following error:

```
 *** Warning: GenericResourceDir doesn't point to a valid resource directory.
                   the -sGenericResourceDir=... option can be used to set this.

    Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
    Operand stack:
       boxfont   Times-Roman
    Execution stack:
       %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   .findfontop   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   .findfontop   .findfontop   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1988   1   3   %oparray_pop   .findfontop   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   .findfontop   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1925   2   3   %oparray_pop
    Dictionary stack:
       --dict:736/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:93/200(L)--
    Current allocation mode is local
    Last OS error: No such file or directory
    Current file position is 646
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 48681 2018-09-16 23:03:58Z karl $) 2.28
!!! Error: Writing to gswin32c failed, error code 1

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 1:
perl.exe c:\msys64\mingw64\share\texmf-dist\scripts\epstopdf\epstopdf.pl "C:/msys64/home/lluis/LAL-DISTRIBUTION/latest/linear-arrangement-library/docshtml//latex/classlal_1_1io_1_1treebank__processor.eps" --outfile="C:/msys64/home/lluis/LAL-DISTRIBUTION/latest/linear-arrangement-library/docshtml//latex/classlal_1_1io_1_1treebank__processor.pdf"
```

If I run `doxygen` with `-d extcmd` part of the output I get is:

```
Executing external command `epstopdf "C:/msys64/home/lluis/LAL-DISTRIBUTION/latest/linear-arrangement-library/docshtml//latex/classlal_1_1io_1_1treebank__processor.eps" --outfile="C:/msys64/home/lluis/LAL-DISTRIBUTION/latest/linear-arrangement-library/docshtml//latex/classlal_1_1io_1_1treebank__processor.pdf"`
```

The whole output can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/rrAMQkTA).

Why does this happen? I can see the error

```
Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
```

Does this mean that a font (`Times-Roman`?) is missing?

Thank you for your help!

Further information: the result of running the command `epstopdf --debug grfig0.eps` is this:

```
* kpsewhich command: kpsewhich
* Input filename: grfig0.eps
* Output filename: grfig0.pdf
* BoundingBox comment: %%BoundingBox:
* Ghostscript command: gswin32c
* Compression: on
* Embedding: on
* Grayscale: off
* PDFSettings: prepress
* Resolution: [use gs default]
* Rotation: None
epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 48681 2018-09-16 23:03:58Z karl $) 2.28
!!! Error: Cannot open grfig0.eps: No such file or directory
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 2:
perl.exe c:\msys64\mingw64\share\texmf-dist\scripts\epstopdf\epstopdf.pl --debug grfig0.eps
```

Notice the error `Cannot open grfig0.eps` file.

Comment: which version of doxygen are you using (i.e. the full information from `doxygen -v`)? Is this during the run of doxygen or are you running the make in the latex directory? In case of doxygen please rerun with `doxygen -d extcmd` so we know which external commands are started. Looks like a mix of Windows and *nix syntax.

Comment: I've updated the post. Doxygen's version is 1.9.2 and after running with `doxygen -d extcmd` the extra command is: `Executing external command "epstopdf "C:/msys64/home/lluis/LAL-DISTRIBUTION/latest/linear-arrangement-library/docshtml//latex/classlal_1_1io_1_1treebank__processor.eps" --outfile="C:/msys64/home/lluis/LAL-DISTRIBUTION/latest/linear-arrangement-library/docshtml//latex/classlal_1_1io_1_1treebank__processor.pdf""`

Comment: I searched the doxygen isues / pull requests list as I vaguely remembered that there have been problems with some ghostscript versions. There have been reports with problems for ghostcript 9.53.3, it was for a different error message but still I would advise to use either an older or newer ghostscript version.

Comment: The problem might indeed be that you are missing the `Times-Roman` font, though I have no experience with this on MSYS2.

Comment: Ok. I don't know how to either get the font or install a different version of ghostscript since I totally depend on the `pacman -S` command of MSYS2. Perhaps somebody else knows something about this issue.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use MSYS2 or would standard Windows or Cygwin work as well.

Comment: I'm trying to make instructions to compile the C++ project from sources so as to distribute the project on Windows. I really couldn't care less if it's MSYS or other. Just something "easy enough" to install and use (even, or, especially, for those who just started programming/developing). The package manager is really what made me choose this, but other options should be fine. I used to use "standard Windows" (I think I know what you mean), but it is no longer an option because I need up-to-date software (like the g++-11 compiler, which is a *must*)